# How to prove that the only curve that minimises the distance between two points in Euclidean space is a straight line?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I am able to prove that one curve in $C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R})$, $r$, that has minimal length connecting two points is a straight line. If these points are $p, q \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then the distance is $|q-p|$. I am, however, struggling to prove that no curves other than a straight line have length $|q-p|$ and have no idea where to start.

For a parameterised curve, $r \in C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R})$, I am finding the length via $\ell(r) = \int_0^1 |\dot{r}(t)|dt$.

Comment: Please edit the question to add your working definition of a _curve_. (Particularly, is a _curve_ continuously differentiable?)

Comment: The traditional proof uses the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) on the functional $\ell(r)$.  (It actually happens to be easier to use the integral of $|\dot{r}|^2$, but it works either way.)  Basically the calculus of variations lets you consider, for every possible curve, the space of all nearby curves.  Then you show that the straight line is the only local minimum of this space.  This is probably enough to satisfy most students, though of course a rigorous proof involves filling in some more details.

Comment: I suspect you could probably prove it without the calculus of variations by making the argument that you can approximate any curve in $C^1([0,1],]\mathbb{R})$ by a curve which is piecewise linear.  Then apply the triangle inequality recursively to show that you can eliminate any "middle point" on this line and decrease the distance.

Answer (score 4):

If $s\in [0,1]$ such that $r(s)$ does not lie on the line segment connecting $r(0)$ and $r(1)$, then by the triangle inequality and the fundamental theorem of calculus we have

\begin{align*} 
\ell(r) &= \int_0^1 |\dot{r}(t)|dt= \int_0^s |\dot{r}(t)|dt + \int_s^1 |\dot{r}(t)|dt\\
 &\geq \left|\int_0^s \dot{r}(t)dt\right| + \left|\int_s^1 \dot{r}(t)dt\right| \\
&= |r(s)-r(0)|+|r(1)-r(s)|>|r(1)-r(0)|.
\end{align*}

#### Remark

Another way to see this is that once we have a definition of length that always satisfies $\ell(r)\geq |r(b)-r(a)|$ for a curve parametrized by $[a,b]$ (which you have already shown apparently, presumably using the fundamental theorem), and satisfies $$\ell(r|_{[a,c]})+\ell(r|_{[c,b]})=\ell(r)$$ for $a<c<b$, then we are done, since if $r(c)$ is not on a line segment with $r(a)$ and $r(b)$ then we have

\begin{align*} 
\ell(r) &= \ell(r|_{[a,c]})+\ell(r|_{[c,b]})\\
 &\geq |r(c)-r(a)|+ |r(b)-r(c)|\\
&>|r(b)-r(a)|.
\end{align*}

This is useful to keep in mind when considering curves not parametrized smoothly, using more general definitions of arc-length.